# How to do mesh plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to make a plot like this:-

 [image]

I can use this formula to plot it : `NearField = r^2/l` 

  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ where  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ r = the radius of the transducer 

 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ and  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ l = the ultrasound wavelength

Here is my code :

```
colormap(hsv);
l=0.0001:0.00015:0.0015;
r=0.001:0.001:0.01; 
[x,y]=meshgrid(r,l);
nearField = x.^2/y;
mesh(r,l,nearField)
```

When I plot it, I get the following :

[image]

Why do I not get the plot like in first figure?

Comment: from the article it seems to be r^2/l and not 2*r/l.

Comment: @Benoit_11 yes it is ,,thank you

Comment: here is the article http://www.electrotherapy.org/modality/ultrasound-therapy

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong coordinates. The first seems to use polar coordinates instead of x,y. Also your r is called radius, which means that r²=x²+y². You have to transform the formular in x,y coordinates to use mesh. I don't think, that there is a matlab function which does this automatically :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use mesh in the bottom line. Plot3 or surf commands should do want you want (the first one draws lines, the second one draws a surface).
I hope it was helpful.